# I am looking for good JS Loader and CSS Loader script in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, loader

I am looking for a good JS and CSS Loader for on demand loading Management in jQuery. Can anyone advice good solution ?

Comment: A JQuery Guru is asking for one? ;)

Comment: Hi Reigel,
their are lots plugin development going on so i was checking if any once came cross new plugin or not

Comment: Building and Maintaining Large JavaScript Applications

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/ff728622.aspx

Comment: look for this loader created with JQuery, CSS, AND HTML -> [DCLoader](http://dcwidget.blogspot.pt/2013/06/loading-widget-using-jquery-animations.html)

Comment: I have found one http://requirejs.org/ RequireJS is a JavaScript file and module loader. It is optimized for in-browser use, but it can be used in other JavaScript environments, like Rhino and Node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd written a library called [jaf](http://code.google.com/p/jaf), that has a loader utility. 
It plays well with jQuery

Comment: Added another utility. Labjs many not be suitable with jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You should check [this](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-loader-%E2%80%93-on-demand-lazy-load-with-jquery-ui)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at this http://headjs.com/ or this https://github.com/jameswestgate/extendify/wiki/load